# Homogeneous equilibrium model

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I am trying to calculate the velocity in a pipe with length $L$ and diameter $D$, which is connected to bottom of a pressurized vessel. The vessel dimensions are known and the level of the liquid inside the vessel is known.

I need to figure out the mass flow rate as a function of pressure inside the vessel.  We can ignore the friction losses in the pipe, and the vessel is filled with water.  Also, how can I find new pressure inside the vessel after the valve has been open for 1 second.

[image]

[image: Pressurised water tank]

Comment: new pressure of what? What's this 15 MPa? is this a double phase fluid inside the vessel?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Homework questions are allowed on the site so long as the person asking has attempted to solve the problem and demonstrates their work.  StackExchange Q&A is built around answering specific questions, not doing your homework for you.

Comment: @GlenH7 Exactly what I thought. Have almost the exact same question in my college documents lying around. I wasn't sure if basic pointers on the solution would qualify as an answer. Also I'm still waiting on exact information on the 15 MPa.

Comment: @idkfa I have added another picture showing the formulas that i have used to solve this problem. I am not sure if they are correct and i wanted to get it verified with an expert. If you can do it will be highly helpful.

Comment: Its a Two-Phase fluid, But both phases assumed to be in same velocity. and 15 Mpa is the Pressure inside the reactor Vessel. New pressure means the pressure after 1 sec of opening the valve.@Algo

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks for the reply. This is my first question on stack Exchange, Now i will learn what kind of questions I should post here after, –

Comment: Are both fluids incompressible?

Comment: They are compressible fluids.
Assumptions of HEM:
The main assumption in the homogenous equilib-
rium model is that both gas and liquid pres-
sures and temperatures are equal. The mixture is
described as one fluid with equal velocities of both
phases. The flow is assumed to be steady and isen-
tropic.
Thank you :)